# Openstack tenant creation date

Tags: openstack, keystone

Is there any way to figure out the creation date of a tenant ? 
I can't seem to find a created_at field in the keystone database.
What I have already found was to take the earliest date of creation of all instances by tenant. but it's not that precise and if there is no instance in the tenant well the tenant doesn't show up...

Answer (score 0):

What you have mentioned in the question absolutely right. You can not get tenant creation time. But you can get instance creation time. There is no proper way to find out tenant creation time.